# Android - part of layout not showing up

Tags: android, layout

So, i got this Layout in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/product_grid_product"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="315dp"
android:layout_height="295dp"
android:background="@color/white"
android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/product_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/product_content_buttons_image"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/product_content_buttons"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_discount"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/product_discount_gray"
                android:src="@drawable/product_discount" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_promotion"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/product_promotion_gray"
                android:src="@drawable/product_promotion" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_oportunity"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/product_oportunity_gray"
                android:src="@drawable/product_oportinity" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_new"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/product_new_gray"
                android:src="@drawable/product_new" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/product_content_image_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/product_content_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>                 

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/product_content_details"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/product_content_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Panela de Pressão" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/product_content_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Aço Inox, 1.5L" />        

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/product_content_brand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Marca" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/product_content_price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="10000,00€" />

        </LinearLayout>

                    <!-- starting here -->

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/product_content_ref"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Ref.: 56065196968" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/product_content_stock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Stock [240]" />

        </LinearLayout>

                    <!-- to here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" 
    android:background="@color/gray_lines"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/product_buttons"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shopping_cart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/shopping_cart" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@color/gray_lines"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/remove_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/remove" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@color/gray_lines"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_quantity"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:singleLine = "true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="35sp" />  

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@color/gray_lines"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@color/gray_lines"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/observations_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" 
        android:text="OBS."  
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_text" /> 

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" 
    android:background="@color/gray_lines"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Nevermind the harcoded strings, they're for dummy purposes.
The problem is that anything that I write between the two comments ("starting here" to "to here") is not showing up.

**I've tried increasing the height of the layout but it doesn't work.**

Any help, please?

Comment: Because you have too many items they are being pushed off the screen most likely... either take some out or wrap the entire xml in a scroll view.

Comment: Wouldn't that problem be solved by increasing the layout height? Because I tried it and it didn't work.
I can't use a Scroll View as this layout will be multiplied in a LayoutInflater

Comment: You can't increase the physical height of your device.

Comment: @TronicZomB - You'd be surprised at what a tub of glue and paperclips can do.

Comment: @dymmeh o_O teach me your ways!

Comment: @user2291217 I don't understand what you mean by multiplied in a LayoutInflater?

Comment: Maybe it's because you have two LinearLayouts both having `match_parent` height, so that one of them takes all the place.

Comment: @TronicZomB I'm designing this in a tablet, and this layout is a small portion of the screen. Even when increasing the layout height (and still showing up in the tablet) that part does not shows up

Comment: So wrap this portion in a Scroll view. Also look at what @VasilySochinsky said.

Comment: @TronicZomB as I said earlier, I can't use a scroll view, the view must be "static".

Comment: @user2291217 and it still doesn't make sense why you can't use one.

Comment: @VasilySochinsky that was it! Please write it as an answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have two LinearLayouts both having `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, so that the first one takes all the place.

You should set `android:layout_height` either to a `"wrap_content"` or to a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the non-appearing `LinearLayout` on the same level of the hierarchy as another `LinearLayout`. Both are set to `match_parent` and the first one is consuming the view area.

Try setting them to either `fill_parent` or `wrap_content`.

Comment: `fill_parent` is deprecated version of `match_parent`